# parseint worked only once despite being used multiple times

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to recode something that got outdated with a recent color expansion. I changed the var to reflect the changes but only one of them successfully worked. Out of those, gender works (as is). But most of the rest doesn't.

The thing is,  theColors[parseInt worked only on the "tert", but not on body and wing. The others doesn't even parse the information.

Help please?

```
function showMeYourTrueColors(theSource) { 
// then, put together the translations
var dragonInfo = parseQueryString(theSource);
var breed = theBreeds[parseInt(dragonInfo["style"])] + "</font></b><hr>";
var gender = "|<b><font color=#731d08>" + theGenders[parseInt(dragonInfo["gender"])];
var primary = "<b>Primary Gene:</b> " + theColors[parseInt(dragonInfo["body"])] + " " + primaryGenes[parseInt(dragonInfo["prig"])];
var secondary = "<b>Secondary Gene:</b> " + theColors[parseInt(dragonInfo["wing"])] + " " + secondaryGenes[parseInt(dragonInfo["secg"])];
var tertiary = "<b>Tertiary Gene:</b> " + theColors[parseInt(dragonInfo["tert"])] + " " + tertiaryGenes[parseInt(dragonInfo["tertg"])];
```

EDIT :: The values are here

```
var theColors = ["None", "Maize", "White", "Ice", "Platinum", "Silver", "Grey", "Charcoal", "Coal", "Black", "Obsidian", "Midnight", "Shadow", "Mulberry", "Thistle", "Lavender", "Purple", "Violet", "Royal", "Storm", "Navy", "Blue", "Splash", "Sky", "Stonewash", "Steel", "Denim", "Azure", "Caribbean", "Teal", "Aqua", "Seafoam", "Jade", "Emerald", "Jungle", "Forest", "Swamp", "Avocado", "Green", "Leaf", "Spring", "Goldenrod", "Lemon", "Banana", "Ivory", "Gold", "Sunshine", "Orange", "Fire", "Tangerine", "Sand", "Beige", "Stone", "Slate", "Soil", "Brown", "Chocolate", "Rust", "Tomato", "Crimson", "Blood", "Maroon", "Red", "Carmine", "Coral", "Magenta", "Pink", "Rose", "Heather", "Orchid", "Oilslick", "Sapphire", "Wine", "Mauve", "Moon", "Marigold", "Tan", "Cinnamon", "Spearmint", "Mantis", "Shamrock", "Hunter", "Iris", "Bronze", "Saffron", "Pearl", "Ruby", "Berry", "Hickory", "Cyan", "Ultramarine", "Smoke", "Plum", "Honey", "Copper", "Taupe", "Abyss", "Antique", "Gloom", "Robin", "Spruce", "Pear", "Honeydew", "Amber", "Yellow", "Peach", "Clay", "Brick", "Terracotta", "Bubblegum", "Sanddollar", "Eggplant", "Indigo", "Fern", "Amethyst", "Moss", "Cherry", "Cerulean", "Lead", "Wisteria", "Midnight", "Watermelon", "Sanguine", "Ginger", "Olive", "Tarnish", "Pistachio", "Overcast", "Blackberry", "Grapefruit", "Flint", "Radioactive", "Orca", "Cerise", "Carrot", "Peacock", "Periwinkle", "Cobalt", "Fog", "Sable", "Flaxen", "Metals", "Thicket", "Murk", "Latte", "Peridot", "Cornflower", "Dust", "Grape", "Lapis", "Turquoise", "Thistle", "Mint", "Algae", "Camo", "Chartreuse", "Caramel", "Umber", "Pumpkin", "Blush", "Lavender", "Raspberry", "Garnet", "Dirt", "Cream", "Cottoncandy", "Driftwood", "Auburn", "Buttercup", "Strawberry", "Vermillion", "Fuschia", "Cantaloupe", "Sunset", "Crocodile", "Twilight", "Nightshade", "Eldritch", "Shale"];
var theGenders = ["Male","Female"];
var theBreeds = ["None", "Fae", "Guardian", "Mirror", "Pearlcatcher", "Ridgeback", "Tundra", "Spiral", "Imperial", "Snapper", "Wildclaw", "Nocturne", "Coatl", "Skydancer"];
var primaryGenes = ["Basic", "Iridescent", "Tiger", "Clown", "Speckle", "Ripple", "Bar", "Crystal", "Vipera", "Piebald", "Cherub", "Poison", "Giraffe", "Petals", "Jupiter"];
var secondaryGenes = ["Basic", "Shimmer", "Stripes", "Eye Spots", "Freckle", "Seraph", "Current", "Daub", "Facet", "Hypnotic", "Paint", "Peregrine", "Toxin", "Butterfly", "Hex", "Saturn"];
var tertiaryGenes = ["Basic", "Circuit", "Unknown 2", "Unknown 3", "Gembond", "Underbelly", "Crackle", "Smoke", "Spines", "Okapi", "Glimmer", "Thylacine", "Stained", "Contour"];
var theElements = ["None", "Earth", "Plague", "Wind", "Water", "Lightning", "Ice", "Shadow", "Light", "Arcane","Nature", "Fire"];
```

Sample links generated as theSource

```
progeny?body=15&bodygene=7&breed=8&element=8&gender=1&tert=67&tertgene=10&winggene=13&wings=67&auth=6ad240d36c922b855bc360bf12002c70c9003e97&dummyext=prev.png
```

[copy of the whole code](http://pastebin.com/raw/nmxDgATf)

Comment: maybe you add some more data, like `theBreeds`, and so on.

Comment: what are the values hold by dragonInfo["body"] and dragonInfo["wing"]?

Comment: Edited the post to show the values

Comment: You don't need to use `parseInt()` when you're indexing into an array, JS will automatically convert the index to an integer.

Comment: What's the value of `theSource`?

Comment: I think that's because the `parseInt` function is returning the `NaN` value which significates that the string you've passed to the function is not a number.

After defining `dragonInfo` variable, please put a `console.log(dragonInfo);`, run the code and puts the console's output here. This will permit to see the content of `dragonInfo`.

Comment: theSource is a randomly generated link by putting elements together, editing to show a sample of a link

Comment: Update: still not sure how to fix it. Something definitely broken but not sure what to change parseint with